# Microsoft dll debug - Source not available

Tags: visual-c++

In the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE,PWSTR pCmdLine,int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register the window class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc ={};

    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);
```

I would like to step into `RegisterClass(&wc);`. Currently when I press F11 it steps over the function.

If I step through the assembly then the call stack shows that I'm somewhere in `user32.dll` at the `RegisterClassW()` function.

If I keep going and try to step through my source I get a windows information dialog that states: `Source Not Available`, `Source information is missing from the debug information for this module`.

Is there any way to view the source code, or do you have to be a Microsoft developer?

I found a [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sharedsource/) to Microsoft's Shared Source Initiative and [Code Center Premium](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sharedsource/code-center-premium.aspx). Perhaps that is the only way?

For an unofficial reference one could perhaps look at

- Wine where `RegisterClass` [has been implemented](http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/user32/class.c), but we assume that code is just a guess as to how it really works.
- [ReactOS](http://code.reactos.org/browse/reactos), which also has an implementation of the API.

I suppose there is probably no way to use either of these to debug in Visual Studio.

Comment: What on Earth do you hope to find back there?  It does not have a bug.  Even if you did have source access then you'd still not want to look at it, nothing very pretty happened to that code after 30 years of appcompat.

Comment: I understand that at some point we just have to use the API and ignore the details. But on occasion I would like to know how something works. With the .pdb files I see the function and variable names, but I can't see what it does with the parameters.

Comment: There is no publicly available source code for core Windows API functions